# WP-PageNavi not working properly on custom page

Tags: post, wordpress, categories

I have created a custom page that will display posts only from a specific category and i have also set `wordpress` to show only 4 number of post. Now the problem is that `WP-PageNavi` is not working properly. Here is the code.

```
<div class="sixteen columns latest_post">

<?php query_posts('cat=3', 'posts_per_page=-1=-'); if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) :the_post(); ?>
   <div class="sixteen columns alpha omega outer_box">
       <div class="inner_box articles">

           <!--TITLE OF THE POST -->
           <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>



           <ul class="data">
             <li><?php the_author_posts_link() ?> /</li>
             <li><?php the_category(', ') ?> /</li>
             <li><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> /</li>
             <li><?php comments_number() ?></li>
           </ul>

           <hr>

           <!--THUMBNAIL -->
           <div class="align_thumbnail_right">
              <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('home-thumb'); ?>

           </div>

           <div class="content">
              <!--TEXT -->
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>


             <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><span>Read More</span></a>
           </div>

        </div>

   </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>

<!--PAGINATION -->

<div class="pagination">
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
</div>
```

I applied the plugin on the index page and it seems to be working fine. But when i tried it on a custom page it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add this

```
wp_reset_query();
```

Below

```
wp_pagenavi();
```

Hope it work fine

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9576/wp-pagenavi-with-custom-wp-query

Comment: Hi i tried adding your solution and also the codex provided below and it worked. Just one question how does "wp_reset_query(); function any. I'm still new to PHP and wordpress coding. I tried that line of code in this <?php endwhile; endif ?> and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: as see your start a query above <?php query_posts('cat=3', 'posts_per_page=-1=-'); if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) :the_post(); ?> where you get post from specific category id 3 now you see you added pagenavigation after wp_rese_query which restore your query and hence your wp_pagenavi(); not work so you can just add query after it..... so here all detail you need http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Answer (score 2):

Wp_page navi needs a 'paged' argument in query_post function

go to this link

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

and ctrl+f word 'paged' their, you'll get the answer of your question.

may be it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$args = array(
  'post_type'     =>  'post',
  'post_status'   =>  'publish',
  'posts_per_page'  =>  3,
  'orderby' => 'id',
  'order' => 'desc',
  'paged' => $paged
);  

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
  // do something
endwhile;

if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { 
  echo '<div class="pagination">';
  wp_pagenavi();
  echo '</div>';
}
$wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```